# Any suggestions for an issue with a long PHP variable causing the script to bomb out in Mac OSX?

Tags: php, string, macos, variables, encoding

Ok, this is a strange one.  I've recently moved over to Mac OS running Lion and set up the PHP version that comes with OSX. Everything's running as I expect except for one thing and I can't understand why!?

As part of our CMS, menu data is cached into a php file as:

```
$menuData = unserialize( $menuString );
```

where $menuString is a long string of serialized data.  I've used the same thing successfully on a PC running WAMP and on numerous linux boxes without problems, but since I've moved to the Mac OS, every time I include the file, it prints a long string of question marks (even if the above line is commented out in the file!!).  Initially, the $menuString was around 280k, but I've also tried this with a menu string of less than 6k without success.

Is there a PHP setting somewhere that might exhibit this type of behaviour?  I'm baffled and have tried numerous things!??

Please help!

UPDATE:  I've gone though the PHP.ini line by line on my Mac and the one I was using in WAMP and see no differences so don't expect it's anything directly set in there.  Everything else in the setup is working exactly as I expect and all other site features and functions are working!?  Is there something obvious in terms of native set up that I'm missing?

Comment: file encoding issues perhaps?

Comment: long strings of ? could indicate a character set problem.

Comment: that's what I initially thought, but I've reduced it down to less than 1k and it works as I expect!  Additionally, I've checked the encoding in the php script and the php.ini files and can't seem to notice any encoding differences between my php.ini elsewhere and on the mac!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, long and short of it is I used a workaround in the end.  At the point of creating the big long serialized menuString, I saved that to a txt file with no php in it and then did a

```
$menuData = unserialize( file_get_contents( [Textfile] ) );
```

Seems to have solved the problem!!  I'm still confused as to why it occurs, but at least it's working!

Answer (score 0):

If it happens with that line commented out then it probably isn't that line... Try dos2unix to fix up you line endings... Aside from that grab hex edit and poke around the area for strange nonprinting chars...

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that didn't help much!  The file is regenerated regularly on changes to the menu structure.  I've tried looking for abnormal characters, but there is nothing out of the ordinary (besides it's working on numerous linux boxes and on PC's!

As well as that, if I take the menu string out and replace the line in the file with $menuData = array( 1,2,3 ); it works as normal

Comment: I guess it is a moot point if you have sidestepped it, but I would look at differences in your php.ini and php info looking for a line length or parameter length, etc.

Comment: Grady, thanks - I did that, thinking that was potentially the source of the problem, but could find nothing!?

Comment: If you can find a way to reproduce it staticaly I would be glad to work on it for you.